# Database adapter delete cascade

Tags: soa, jdeveloper, oracle-soa

I am trying to delete some registry with database adapter delete operation. However this table has a relationship.

Sometimes, the action can't execute because foreign key violations.

Is there any way to delete using cascade in Oracle SOA Suite databases adapters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enter your SQL manually, check the documentation in [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/integration.1111/e10231/adptr_db.htm#BDCDJDGC)

Comment: I just thought Oracle SOA Suite had some parameter to configure this "simple" thing. By the way, I also call a procedure in another example, however, in this case, I thought that exist a easier way to proceed. Thx